# Will just any IR remote work with an irDA adaptor?

Tags: remote, irda

Will irDA accept just any old universal remote or does it have to be a special kind?

Answer (score 2):

IrDA has both [signaling and frequency specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association#IrPHY), therefore cannot really be used with remotes; it is designed to facilitate communication between two intelligent pieces of hardware (read: computers).

If you want to be able to receive signals from a remote control then the best thing to do is to get a receiver such as those made by SNK since those are far more liberal with what they accept.